# Making Radio Boxes Multiple Select JS

Tags: javascript

I have this app for Shopify https://apps.shopify.com/product-options
and I have a javascript where if you select a radio box it changes color, but I have two full elements of radio boxes and when I select one option the other option doesn't get selected [when I select no my background for colors goes away and goes on no when I want both to be selected if a user selects it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z7Ii.png)
here is my javascript

```js
<script>
$(window).bind("load", function() {
  
  $(".bold_option_radio  label").click(function() {
    $(".bold_option_radio label").removeClass("selected-label");
    $(this).addClass("selected-label");
  });
});
</script>
```

when I remove my remove class you can select multiple things but can't remove them, I'm new to code and been working on this for a while, any help is appreciated.
Also I can't change HTML classes because its a Shopify app but it is possible because my competitor does it.

Comment: Radio buttons can only be selected once at a time. Try using a checkbox input instead to select (tick) multiple options.

Comment: @Baruch I have two radio boxes with two options each, I want both radio boxes to have color when selected I have two options on one radio box then I select one it goes into a different color, then I have another radio box and I select one option from it it goes into the same color as the other one but only one gets colored. Want to be able to have two colors selected from two different radio boxes on one selected option. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Simply - let not them have the same class and access them across ID. Please mark my answer as best;

Edit 18. 14. 2020
If you cannot edit html you can try this:

```js
$(".selected-label").each(function(index) {
    $(this).removeClass("selected-label");
    $(this).setAttribute("id", "selected-label" + (index + 1))
}
```

Your labels have the IDs in syntax selected-label1, selected-label2, selected-label3...